# Losing duplicate column names when flattening list-of-lists into dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

This type of "flattening lists into dataframes" question has been asked a few times, however I could not find a solution that helped with my particular issue. I've made a small example below. In general, when using `httr` in R to get data from APIs, most of the data APIs that I have used to fetch data return the data in a similar nested-list-of-lists format, that looks something like this:

```
nested_list = list(
  list(
    name = 'joe', 
    match = 13, 
    team = list(
      list(
        name = 'teama'          
      ),
      list(
        name = 'teamb'
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    name = 'tom', 
    match = 15, 
    team = list(
      list(
        name = 'teamc'          
      ),
      list(
        name = 'teamd'
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I had been working on a good function to flatten nested lists-of-lists for a while, since flat dataframes are much easier to work with for analytics in R. Here is my current approach flattening to 2D:

```
nested_list %>%
  purrr::map(unlist) %>%
  purrr::map(t) %>%
  purrr::map(as_tibble) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows() %>%
  readr::type_convert() # optional, to format column types
```

This approach generally works okay, however after the `as_tibble` map is called, if there are duplicate keys in the nested list-of-lists, then they are replaced with column names V1, V2, V3, etc. I show the steps below that are leading to this issue:

**unlist**

```
> nested_list %>% purrr::map(unlist)
[[1]]
     name     match team.name team.name 
    "joe"      "13"   "teama"   "teamb" 

[[2]]
     name     match team.name team.name 
    "tom"      "15"   "teamc"   "teamd"
```

**unlist and transpose**

```
> nested_list %>% purrr::map(unlist) %>% purrr::map(t)
[[1]]
     name  match team.name team.name
[1,] "joe" "13"  "teama"   "teamb"  

[[2]]
     name  match team.name team.name
[1,] "tom" "15"  "teamc"   "teamd"
```

**unlist and transpose and as_tibble**

```
> nested_list %>% purrr::map(unlist) %>% purrr::map(t) %>% purrr::map(as_tibble)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  name  match team.name V4   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 joe   13    teama     teamb

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  name  match team.name V4   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 tom   15    teamc     teamd
```

In my full dataset, there are plenty of duplicate column names, too many to code manual fixes to update these column names. Rather, it would be good if the duplicate names were handled better (perhaps with a `team.name.1` and `team.name.2`).

Is there another way to flatten this list-of-lists to preserve the column names like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as_tibble` has the parameter `.name_repair`. Setting that to `"unique"` does what you want:

```
nested_list %>%
  purrr::map(unlist) %>% 
  purrr::map(t) %>% 
  purrr::map(as_tibble, .name_repair = "unique") %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows() %>%
  readr::type_convert()


# A tibble: 2 x 4
  name  match team.name...3 team.name...4
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>         <chr>        
1 joe      13 teama         teamb        
2 tom      15 teamc         teamd
```

Note that we pass this option to the `purrr::map()` call, and it is passed on to the `as_tibble` call.

Another tip: if you replace your last `purrr::map()` with `purrr:map_dfr()`, the `bind_rows()` is automatically done.